# Troubles with Russian symbols in Maven resource filtering

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to send some russian text to *.properties file with Maven resource filtering(maven-resources-plugin) from profiles in pom. So, when i'm sending English symbols it works well, but when i'm trying to get values in Russian from parameters(located in properties file) - encoding brokes. Project encoding for all of the files in IntelliJ is set to UTF-8.
In filtered file Russian text is showing normally. But when i'm getting it from file with getProperty method it shows me this:
[Encoding error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhKIG.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<delimiters>
  <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
  <delimiter>@</delimiter>
</delimiters>
```

So the following would be filtered as well:
env.name=@replacement.value@